# htaccess rewrite URL queries with ampersand symbol in the variables value

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mysqli

I have a URL structure that i am changing at the moment, i have managed to get the rewrite working fine only problem is the & symbol that is inside some of the fields within the database before I started messing with the htaccess file i had this problems easily resolved in php using the str_replace function

```
$url = str_replace("&", "%26", $url);
```

My htaccesss file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?$ job_title.php?jobtitle=$1 [L]
```

The old URL structure is like this:

```
http://localhost/website/job_title.php?jobtitle=Administration-Jobs
```

The new URL structure is like this:

```
http://localhost/website/Administration-Jobs
```

i'm happy with the structure of the urls but now i'm having issues with the & symbol all over again

Comment: Not clear what you want from rewrite rules to do?

Comment: I'm pretty much getting a file not found error from lets say: 
http://localhost/website/c&q-jobs
or
http://localhost/website/c%26q-jobs

Comment: ok try my solution from your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25932310/548225